# Some questions about XMPP/Jabber capabilities

Tags: xmpp

we're in the process of building some functionality on top of an existing Jabber client. I'm wondering if the following is possible :

1. Adding metadata/custom fields per user such as gender, age
2. Is is possible to search by the custom fields (for example, get me all females between 20 and 30 who live in Canada)
3. Can you get a list of "who's online"
4. Can you message someone who's not in your friend's list ?
5. Does the protocol support file/image transfer ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. This would require support for [XEP-0055](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html#usecases-search) with dataforms (I think).  I can't say as to whether any server will support this out of the box or some customization might be required.
3. Only if it supports the appropriate ad-hoc command from [XEP-0133](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html#get-online-users-list).
4. Yes.  You can message any JID.
5. Yes, pretty much any XMPP client will have this already.  There is support for multiple methods of transfer built into the protocol.

In the future, you should limit the scope of your questions or you risk having them closed.  Asking multiple questions in one question typically leads them being closed.